# PDO Fetch statement only retrieves first column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As the title states, I am only able to grab the id column, I am getting an Undefined index error for the others.

My code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $presh = $_SESSION['id'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = :id");
    $id = $presh;
    $stmt->execute(array(':id'=>$id));
    $accountinfo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Later on in my code I reference it as such:

```
Karma <span id="kcurrent"><?php echo $accountinfo["karmacurrent"]; ?></span> | <span id="ktotal"><?php echo $accountinfo["karmatotal"]; ?></span>
```

The rows do exist and they are filled, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can only select the `id` column because that is all you have in the query.

Try something like this

```
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    $presh = $_SESSION['id'];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, karmacurrent FROM users WHERE id = :id");

    $id = $presh;

    $stmt->execute(
        array(
            ':id'=>$id
        )
    );

    $accountinfo = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Basically you were only retrieving the `ID` from the table instead of the other columns.

Comment: Shoot, just needed to modify the SQL query to SELECT *,

Comment: @0n35 It's best not to use * when getting the columns, rather select the columns all by names, e.g. - SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM `table_name`.

Comment: @Darren Can you explain me why?

Comment: @inetphantom because it could add unwanted load times to your queries, especially if they are large. Imagine if you went to the shops and only wanted to buy some milk, but you used the "buy all" (`*`) select, makes the query rather large doesn't it? You should only ever select what you need, not what you have access to!

Comment: See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-optimization.html